# How to load this txt file to MySQL?

Tags: php, python, mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I have been trying for a while now to import this kind of file to phpmyadmin and with external PHP infile load code, however I cant seem to get the result I would like. I'm not too sure whether I am putting the correct data within the format specific options.

Columns separated with: (space character)
Columns enclosed with: -
Columns escaped with: -
Lines terminated with: auto (\n)

Could someone propose a suggestion as what I should do? The snippet of text below is what the text file looks like (without the bullet points).

Perhaps phpmyadmin is not the way to go?

I would show you guys pictures but I don't have the reputation...yet.

If this helps, I have a link from where I got the dataset:
- https://snap.stanford.edu/data/web-Amazon.html

The layout is shown in the link, I would use Python if need be, though I don't have the experience with that language, I'm willing to use a parser which is provided in the link (wouldn't know where to start).

- -product/productId- B000068VBQ
- -product/title- Fisher-Price Rescue Heroes: Lava Landslide
- -product/price- 8.88
- -review/userId- unknown
- -review/profileName- unknown
- -review/helpfulness- 11/11
- -review/score- 2.0
- -review/time- 1042070400
- -review/summary- Requires too much coordination
- -review/text- I bought this software for my 5 year old. He has a couple of the other RH software games..

Comment: You would need to recode it into a csv or tsv file.  You'll also need a schema to create the table.  If you can convert it to JSON, then MongoDB could be an alternative.  If there is a lot of it (>2Gb), you might want to use something like Google BigQuery, which can import either csv or json and uses a simplified schema.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that quick reply, by recode do you mean changing the layout of the format for all the records? That would take a while if that is what you mean, there are over 10,000 records. Unless there is a way to go about it?
I do have the schema which has the table with the relevant columns.

Comment: 10,000 isn't very many.  You need to figure out what needs to change and a script to do it.  You probably need to write a csv file, and python has a `csv` module that makes this fairly simple.  The parser is on that web site you posted.  Put them together and loop through the data.